# How to compile OpenThread examples on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, docker, vagrant, openthread

How can I compile the OpenThread examples on Mac OS?
The scripts supplied in the repository do not work, because they use apt-get which is not available in Mac OS.
Is there some kind of guide on how this can be achived (either compiling natively or in a VM or container)?

Comment: What's an OpenThread example?

Comment: @Matt The examples that can be found on their GitHub. https://github.com/openthread/openthread/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PR seeks to add Mac (i.e. brew) support to the setup script: https://github.com/openthread/openthread/pull/2332

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out ASAP and approve your answer if it works for me.